# rtw8822 firware does not load for custom kernel

Tags: wifi, firmware, lfs

Hi I am building Linux From Scratch, I managed to get a working linux! but now I cannot get `wlan0` working. When I boot ubuntu I can see the wifi is rtw8822be, so I enabled it in `.config`, recompiled and rebooted into a new system, but the firmware does not load:

```
$ dmesg | grep 8822
rtw_8822be 0000:04:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0003)
rtw_8822be 0000:04:00.0: Direct firmware load for rtw88/rtw8822b_fw.bin failed with error -2
rtw_8822be 0000:04:00.0: failed to request firmware
rtw_8822be 0000:04:00.0: failed to load firmware
rtw_8822be 0000:04:00.0: failed to setup chip efuse info
rtw_8822be 0000:04:00.0: failed to setup chip information
rtw_8822be: probe of 0000:04:00.0 failed with error -22
```

I downloaded firmware for the same version of kernel (6.2) and unpacked 400MB firmware.tar.gzip into /lib/firmware:

```
$ ls /lib/firmware/rtw88/
README  rtw8723d_fw.bin  rtw8821c_fw.bin  rtw8822b_fw.bin  rtw8822c_fw.bin  rtw8822c_wow_fw.bin
```

What can I do now?

While on Ubintu I did this:

```
$ lspci|ag -i wifi
04:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8822BE 802.11a/b/g/n/ac WiFi adapter
```

Kernel 6.2. mobo asus b450i rog-strix.

Comment: 400 GB?! That's an awful lot of space. Did you mean 400MB?

Comment: @rando fixed thanks